# Why POST request can be changed to GET on the way from NGINX to PHP

Tags: php, nginx, post, php-7

I have next very strange situation:

1. POST request to the server.
2. In nginx logs I see something like that: *IP-ADDRESS - ce5c8fb7-0a40-4c4e-9b8e-779cae54d4ad-1522849217932 [11/Jun/2018:11:37:38 +0000] "POST /unsubscribe HTTP/1.1" 400 69 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.181 Safari/537.36"*
3. So, nginx is seeing that request like POST
4. But if I do `echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']`, I will have "GET" as output.
5. This happens only for one endpoint "/unsubscribe". For all other endpoints POST request works fine.
6. There no rules in configs related to "unsubscribe" word.

I did try a lot of variants, tests, turn off cache where is possible. But still same behavior. Probably someone has idea what would be good to try in that situation or someone had same problems before?

P.S.
On there server I have Ubuntu + Nginix + PHP 7.0. Not sure, but probably it can be related to PHP version somehow, because some time ago we upgraded from 5.6 to 7.0

Comment: Maybe redirect or second request in same time

Comment: @ArtemIlchenko Thank you. But there no redirects in logs and exactly one record for my request(doesn't look like I have second request somehow) :(